# How to do a graceful restart in Apache 2.4? In Apache 2.2 this used to work: ap_signal_parent( SIGNAL_PARENT_RESTART_GRACEFUL );

Tags: restart, apache2.4

What's the equivalent of

```
ap_signal_parent( SIGNAL_PARENT_RESTART_GRACEFUL );
```

in Apache 2.4?
I have a module in cpp which used to make the above call to do a graceful restart in Apache 2.2.
I am not finding the equivalent in 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be the same Windows-specific code in 2.2 and 2.4.